# open vnc - How to use space in username

Tags: remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to a server with a username with space.

```
open vnc://<user ? name>@<ip>

open vnc://user\ name@<ip> // not working
```

Error:

```
The file ... does not exist.
```

Comment: How did you get a username with a space in it?!

Comment: What different does it make?

Comment: Well, you are having a problem with a space in the username!

Comment: So your suggestion is that I make the user change the user name :-)

Comment: AFAIK it is not even _allowed_ to have a space in the username. So how that came to be could indicate some more serious problem.

Comment: Thanks I will tell the user that - any suggestion to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127127/discussion-between-chris-g-and-michael-hampton).